# ng-grid cannot select item after remove a row

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

```
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
                        });
                        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
```

The last line simply not working: $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);

```
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
                            $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
                        });
```

Not working either.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggling, I find a work around to this issue, although it looks quite complex to fix such a small issue, but it works. And I have not found anything else better to make it work. Once I found I will post here.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
                    });    
setTimeout(selectARow, 0);
function selectARow() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        if ($scope.myData.length == index) {
            $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(Math.max(0, index - 1), true);
        }
        else {
            $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
        }
    });
};
```

The idea is after `$scope.myData.splice(index, 1);` removed a row from the array, it will need some time to remove the row from grid and reset the selected item to the first record in the grid. we need to do `$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);` after all these steps have been done. So, `setTimeout(selectARow, 0);` is used for this purpose. The rest code is just to select a proper row after the delete.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll have to pick the next rowindex (or previous if it was the last line of the grid).

Something like this should work:

```
var indexToRemove = parseInt(index);
var indexToFocus = ($scope.myData.length > (indexToRemove + 1) ? (indexToRemove + 1): (indexToRemove - 1));
$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(indexToRemove , false);
$scope.myData.splice(indexToRemove , 1);
$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(indexToFocus , true);
```